# Why folder size differs so much between the folder alone and all of the folder contents?

Tags: windows, file, directory, size

In Windows 10, I go to 'C:\Users' and right-click on the folder with my username and select "Properties". 
***The file size is 5.92GB, 44,507 files and 10,457 folders.***

I open up this folder with my username and I use the key combination CTRL + A and then right-click, and select "Properties". 
***The file size is 1.41GB, 10,721 files, 721 folders.***

Why is that? Why the folder alone and the whole contents of the folder size differs so much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably due to hidden files and folders.
You need in folder click to bookmarks View in top menu and click to checkbox hidden elements.  When you enable hidden element you can use CTRL + A and then right-click, and select "Properties".

Comment: True. The hidden "AppData" folder was the missing part. Dang! How could I forget about that.